# Angular js application simple example with controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I am new to angular js.
and i am trying to separate js files in to many functional pieces.
and i made a controller out side of app.js and it is not working =(

here is a code of app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', [
  'ui.rotuer',
  'app.controller'
]).config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home/views/home.html',
            controller: 'MyCtrl1'
          })
        .state('contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: 'home/views/contact.html',
          });
});
```

and

here is my controller part.

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */
angular.module('app.controller', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message="this is message from controller";
  }]);
```

i attached both files in html files. so both are loaded in html.
and each view (html files) are available.

how do i make it right?

Comment: First of all ui-router is mispelled. Secondly, did you put the scripts in the correct order?

Comment: haha it is so embarrassing. it was from 'ui.router'. i checked it quite several times but it was .. 
Thanks a lot =) @JoshSGman

Comment: and the order thing, i need to put app.js first, right?

Comment: The order might not actually matter in this case, but If it does, it would make more sense if app.js loads after app.controller module, given that app.js is dependent on app.controller

Comment: If you don't mind, can you vote up my answer, if it fixed it for you? THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelled ui-router, additionally, make sure that that app.js is loading after you have defined app.controller in your scripts.